# \hat{} not appearing in equation with transpose?

Tags: equations

Why does the first bracket not display the \hat{\beta}, I cut and pasted from the second one so they are exactly the same? I guess it has to do with the fact that the first expression is transposed?

```
\documentclass{article} % Your input file must contain these two lines
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small} 
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{example}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[%
  font=small,
  labelfont=bf,
 figurewithin=section,
  tablewithin=section,
  tableposition=top
 ]{caption}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
   \def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols l}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} % plus the \end{document} command at the end
\parskip = 1pc %change spacing between paragraphs
\parindent = 0pc %change paragraph indentation
\pagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagestyle{plain}



\begin{equation}

SSR = (y-X \hat{\beta})^{T}(y-X \hat{\beta})   

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with a document class and the packages you use. It works in my minimal setup with only amsmath loaded.

Comment: OK I added an full example above I've added all the packages I am using in case one of them is causing the problem

Comment: If you remove the empty lines in the equation environment this works just fine for me. Having them should have thrown some errors, though.

Comment: That's it please submit it as an answer and I'll make sure I tick it

Comment: I think right now the question is a little too specific. Also I cannot provide a explenation why empty lines cause problems in math environment. Maybe you could modify the question so it contains the error message you get so other people can find it more easily.

Comment: @frankundfrei -- blank lines are equivalent to `\par`, and paragraph breaks are not (by definition -- built into tex) allowed in math, either in-line or display.